# How to test external loaded modules in Angular2 using jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, karma-jasmine, topojson

I am using [Datamap](http://datamaps.github.io/) to create world chart map.

In my component I have added it like this:

```
 declare const Datamap;
 this.map = new Datamap({element: document.getElementById('map-container'),
  fills: {
    TOP: 'rgb(14, 120, 230)',
    OTHER: 'rgb(170, 209, 242)',
    defaultFill: 'rgb(211, 211, 211)'
  },
  data: data,
    geographyConfig: {
      popupTemplate: function(geo, data) {
        this.getTemplate(geo,data)
      },
      popupOnHover : true,
      highlightOnHover : false
    }
  });
```

When I run test cases for this then I am getting this error:

`include d3.js (v3.0.3 or greater) and topojson on this page before creating a new map`

So I imported d3 and topojson like this:

```
  import * as topojson from '../../topojson.min.js';
  import * as d3 from '../../d3.min.js';
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
  Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'
```

My Imports in spec file:

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations : [WorldChart
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    NvD3Module,
    MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ],
  // providers :[
  //   {provide: d3},
  //   {provide: topojson}
  // ]
})
   .compileComponents();
 }));
```

I am not sure how can I remove this.